# Unable to execute stored procedure using named query in nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am facing strange problem while executing stored procedure using nhibernate. When I am going through stack trace then I got Index Out Of Range exception and name of property / column. I research on google and stackoverflow and found that if any property is mapped two times then it cause problem. I checked all mapping but nothing seems to be helpful for me.
Here I am writing all hbl files and codes which I am using.

Hbm file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="ConsoleApplication2" namespace="ConsoleApplication2" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

    <class name="tARCustomer" table="tARCustomer" lazy="true" >
        <id name="fCustomerID">
            <generator class="guid.comb" />
        </id>
        <version name="fTimestamp" generated="always" unsaved-value="null" type="BinaryBlob">
            <!--<column name="fTimestamp" not-null="false" sql-type="timestamp"/>-->
        </version>
        <property name="fCustomerNumber">
        </property>
        <property name="fName">
        </property>
        <property name="fAddress1">
        </property>
        <property name="fAddress2">
        </property>
        <property name="fCity">
        </property>
        <property name="fLocalityID">
        </property>
        <property name="fPostalCode">
        </property>
        <property name="fDeliveryMethod">
        </property>
        <property name="fDoNotAllowFinanceCharges">
        </property>
        <property name="fNotes">
        </property>
        <property name="fInactive">
        </property>
        <property name="fCompanyID">
        </property>
        <property name="fPropertyID">
        </property>
        <property name="fEnterpriseID">
        </property>
        <property name="fDateAdded">
        </property>
        <property name="fAddedBy">
        </property>
        <property name="fDateModified">
        </property>
        <property name="fModifiedBy">
        </property>
        <property name="fShipToSameAsBilling">
        </property>
        <property name="fShipToAddress1">
        </property>
        <property name="fShipToAddress2">
        </property>
        <property name="fShipToCity">
        </property>
        <property name="fShipToLocalityID">
        </property>
        <property name="fShipToPostalCode">
        </property>
        <property name="fCustomerTotalBalance">
        </property>
        <property name="fSuspend">
        </property>
        <property name="fCreditLimitActive">
        </property>
        <property name="fCreditLimitAmt">
        </property>


        <bag name="Invoices" inverse="true" cascade="none" lazy="true">
            <key column="fCustomerID" />
            <one-to-many class="tARInvoice" />
        </bag>


        <many-to-one name="Enterprise" insert="false" update="false" cascade="none" class="ConsoleApplication2.tSCEnterprise,ConsoleApplication2"
            column="fEnterpriseID" not-null="false"/>



        <many-to-one name="Company" insert="false" update="false" cascade="none" class="ConsoleApplication2.tSCCompany,ConsoleApplication2"
            column="fCompanyID" not-null="false"/>



        <many-to-one name="Property" insert="false" update="false" cascade="none" class="ConsoleApplication2.tSCProperty,ConsoleApplication2"
            column="fPropertyID" not-null="false"/>


    </class>

    <!--<loader query-ref="ar_tARCustomer_ReadOverdueByContext"/>-->

    <sql-query name="ar_tARCustomer_ReadOverdueByContext" >
        <return class="tARCustomer">
        </return>
        exec ar_tARCustomer_ReadOverdueByContext :CustomerActive ,:CompanyID,:PropertyID ,:DateFrom, :DateTo, :InvoiceTypes
    </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

and domain class code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    [Serializable]
    public class tARCustomer 
    {
        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="tARCustomer"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public tARCustomer()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="tARCustomer"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fCustomerID">The Payment Type ID.</param>
        public tARCustomer(System.Guid fCustomerID)
        {
            ////base.ID = fCustomerID;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets customer ID.
        /// </summary> 
        public virtual System.Guid fCustomerID { get; set; }

        public virtual string fCustomerNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual string fName { get; set; }

        public virtual string fAddress1 { get; set; }

        public virtual string fAddress2 { get; set; }

        public virtual string fCity { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid? fLocalityID { get; set; }

        public virtual string fPostalCode { get; set; }

        public virtual string fDeliveryMethod { get; set; }

        public virtual bool fDoNotAllowFinanceCharges { get; set; }

        public virtual string fNotes { get; set; }

        public virtual bool fInactive { get; set; }

        public virtual bool fSuspend { get; set; }

        public virtual bool fCreditLimitActive { get; set; }

        public virtual decimal fCreditLimitAmt { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid? fCompanyID { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid? fPropertyID { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid? fEnterpriseID { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime? fDateAdded { get; set; }

        public virtual string fAddedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTime? fDateModified { get; set; }

        public virtual string fModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual byte[] fTimestamp { get; set; }

        public virtual bool fShipToSameAsBilling { get; set; }

        public virtual string fShipToAddress1 { get; set; }

        public virtual string fShipToAddress2 { get; set; }

        public virtual string fShipToCity { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid? fShipToLocalityID { get; set; }

        public virtual string fShipToPostalCode { get; set; }

        public virtual decimal fCustomerTotalBalance { get; set; }        

        #endregion


        public virtual tSCCompany Company { get; set; }
        public virtual tSCProperty Property { get; set; }
        public virtual tSCEnterprise Enterprise { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<tARInvoice> Invoices { get; set; }


        #region Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// To retrieve Hash Code.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The retrieve hash code.</returns>
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.GetHashCode();            
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I am using following code to call sp.

```
var dd = session.GetNamedQuery("ar_tARCustomer_ReadOverdueByContext")
                       .SetParameter("CustomerActive", 2)
                       .SetParameter("CompanyID", Guid.Parse("3C5F1D66-75F3-4762-BAA1-6A0ADA8D6DD4"))
                       .SetParameter("PropertyID", Guid.Parse("53C4B765-C1B1-4353-98CB-AC9FBCE84F0C"))
                       .SetParameter("DateFrom", DateTime.Parse("5/1/2001"))
                       .SetParameter("DateTo", DateTime.Parse("4/24/2013"))
                       .SetParameter("InvoiceTypes", "Manual")
                       .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(tARCustomer)))
                       .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.ToList).List();
```

Except for that I tried so many combination but I am not able to solve it.
I have following stored procedure.

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[ar_tARCustomer_ReadOverdueByContext]  

  @CustomerActive  int,      
  @CompanyID   uniqueidentifier,   
  @PropertyID   uniqueidentifier,   
  @OverdueDateFrom  datetime,   
  @OverdueDateTo  datetime,   
  @InvoiceTypes   varchar(100)  

AS  

----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
-- Name:     ar_tARCustomer_ReadOverdueByContext    
-- Purpose:  Get all customers with overdue invoices matching the given criteria at this point in the hierarchy       
--    
-- Input:    N/A    
-- Output:   Recordset containing all customers with overdue invoices matching the given criteria  
-- Return:   0 = Success    
--           >0 = Error    
--    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    

SET NOCOUNT ON;  -

SELECT fName
from tARCustomer
```

One more thing I want to say that when I am using select * from tARCustomer then this procedure is worked for me but when I am using select fCustomerID from tARCustomer then it gives error.

I don't know why it happens but am not able to solve it. Please help me to solve out this problem as soon as possible,

Here I am putting stack trace of exception.

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was caught
  Message=could not execute query
[ exec ar_tARCustomer_ReadOverdueByContext @p0 ,@p1,@p2 ,@p3, @p4, @p5 ]
  Name:CustomerActive - Value:2  Name:CompanyID - Value:3c5f1d66-75f3-4762-baa1-6a0ada8d6dd4  Name:PropertyID - Value:53c4b765-c1b1-4353-98cb-ac9fbce84f0c  Name:DateFrom - Value:5/1/2001 12:00:00 AM  Name:DateTo - Value:4/24/2013 12:00:00 AM  Name:InvoiceTypes - Value:Manual
[SQL: exec ar_tARCustomer_ReadOverdueByContext @p0 ,@p1,@p2 ,@p3, @p4, @p5]
  Source=NHibernate
  SqlString=exec ar_tARCustomer_ReadOverdueByContext @p0 ,@p1,@p2 ,@p3, @p4, @p5
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
       at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ListCustomQuery(ICustomQuery customQuery, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.List()
       at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Test\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 23
  InnerException: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
       Message=fCustomerID
       Source=System.Data
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
            at NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
            at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name)
            at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String[] names, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetKeyFromResultSet(Int32 i, IEntityPersister persister, Object id, IDataReader rs, ISessionImplementor session)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRowFromResultSet(IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, LockMode[] lockModeArray, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, IList hydratedObjects, EntityKey[] keys, Boolean returnProxies)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
            at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
       InnerException:
```

Thanks.

Comment: need urgent help on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` on the result of your query the columns returned in the query must map one to one with the properties on the class you are loading with data.

Your query posted above only returns a single column `fName1` - it is missing all of the other properties of your class `tARCustomer`.

The thrown exception is telling you the issue - that it cannot find result column `fCustomerID`. To illustrate modify your select statement to include this and re-run it, the exception will then highlight the next missing field.

Comment: But when I need only few columns then what can I do. Actually I have procedure which pull few records from customer table and few records from other tables and I need to call that SP using nhibernate. Plz let me know what I have to do. Thanks for taking a look on this problem.

Comment: @Awadhendra not sure I follow, if you only need a few columns you could create a smaller class with just a couple of properties and read the results into that using the AliasToBeanResultTransformer or you could ditch that altogether and explicitly read the results of the query manually. Could you perhaps clarify the exact problem for me so I can help further?